# Primary key integer returning incremented on lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

**Edit:** I have determined that this is only an issue when using Sequelize with SQLite. I had no problems after switching to Postgres. This question still stands though.

In Sequelize, I have `Server` and `Seller` models with a many-to-many relationship. The join model is `IgnoredSellers`.

```js
const Server = sequelize.define('server', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true
  }
}, { timestamps: false });

const Seller = sequelize.define('seller', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
}, { timestamps: false });

const IgnoredSeller = sequelize.define('ignored_seller', {}, { timestamps: false });

Server.belongsToMany(Seller, { through: IgnoredSeller });
Seller.belongsToMany(Server, { through: IgnoredSeller });
```

Here's a sample row in the `servers` table:

| id |
| --- |
| 84805370821310096 |

When I try `Server.findByPk(84805370821310096)`, the returned Server instance has an `id` of `84805370821310100`, which looks like an incremented version of the stored value.

```js
const server = await Server.findByPk(serverId); // 84805370821310096 is passed in

// Executing (default): SELECT `id` FROM `servers` AS `server` WHERE `server`.`id` = '84805370821310096';

console.log('SERVER:', server.id); // 84805370821310100 is returned
```

So when I try `server.addSeller(seller)`, I get a foreign key constraint error because the Server instance ID `84805370821310100` doesn't match any ID in the `server` table.

```js
// Continued from above code
const seller = await Seller.findOne({ where: { title: sellerTitle }});
const ignoredSeller = await server.addSeller(seller);

// Executing (default): INSERT INTO `ignored_sellers` (`serverId`,`sellerId`) VALUES (84805370821310100,'amp');
// Failed to insert ignored seller: ForeignKeyConstraintError [SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError]: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

What's causing this to happen?

Answer (score -1):

You have to define IgnoredSeller like this -

```js
const IgnoredSeller = sequelize.define(
    "ignored_seller",
    {
      sellerId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      serverId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    {
       timestamps: false
    }
)
```

Comment: The issue isn't the database structure. I have verified that it's building correctly.

Comment: you can add     Server.belongsToMany(Seller, { through: IgnoredSeller, foreignKey: "serverId",  constraints: false });
Seller.belongsToMany(Server, { through: IgnoredSeller,   foreignKey: "sellerId",  constraints: false });